Has anyone encountered a Segmentation fault when executing the effect method of econml on CentOS 6.3 using Python 3.9?
gdb bt information:
in dict_traverse ()
in deduce_unreachable ()
in collect ()
in collect_with_callback ()
in PyGC_Collect ()
in Py_FinalizeEx ()
in Py_RunMain ()
in Py_BytesMain ()
in __GI_____strtof_l_internal (nptr=<optimized out>, endptr=<optimized out>, group=<optimized out>, loc=<optimized out>) at strtod_l.c:1243

I tried update the EconML package, but it didn't affect
